# Нахождение и замена текста.

Tags: php

У нас в тексте есть вот такие ссылки...

http://www.video.com/tube/videos/433580/classic-whore-vanessa-del-rio-is-loving.html

Как сделать так, чтобы эти ссылки заменялись на [смотреть](http://www.video.com/tube/videos/433580/classic-whore-vanessa-del-rio-is-loving.html )?

Answer (score 2):

Ну, например так:

```
preg_replace('/http:\/\/[^\s]+\.html/','<a href="$0">смотреть</a>',$str);
```

Штука заменяет все строки, которые начинаются с http://, состоят из чего угодно, кроме пробелов, а оканчиваются на .html.

Более общий случай:

```
preg_replace('/(http:\/\/)|(www\.)[^\s]+\.[a-z34]{2,6}/','<a href="$0">смотреть</a>',$str);
```

В данном случае возможно, чтобы ссылка начналась с www или http, а заканчивалась на любое(почти) расширение. 34 - это два символа, чтобы покрыть такие расширения как mp3, mpeg4

Comment: мне нужно чтобы заменялись только ссылки с http://www.video.com/tube

Comment: а так получаеться и внутрение заменяются

Comment: ну добавьте условие, аля

preg_replace('/http:\/\/www.video.com/tube[^\s]+\.html/','<a href="$0">смотреть</a>',$str);

Comment: что -то не работает...

Comment: shurik забыл заэкранировать слэш и точки =)
    
    preg_replace('/http:\/\/www\.video\.com\/tube[^\s]+\.html/','<a href="$0">смотреть</a>',$str);

А так - он все правильно сказал